# Sending URL params via a form_tag and select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using nested resources, and in order to make a new `Round`, you need to have the id of its `Case`, so my `routes.rb` includes the following:

```
resources :cases do
  resources :rounds
end
```

So, when a user hits the 'new round' button on the homepage, it first directs them to a page where they can pick a case that the round belongs to, before redirecting to the round form.

For the pick_case view, I have the following:

```
<%= form_tag new_case_round_path, method: :get do |f| %>

  <%= f.select_tag :case_id,
    options_for_select(Case.all.collect { |c| [c.title, c.id] }),
    class: "chosen-select" %><br/>

  <%= f.submit_tag "Create round", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

However, rails forces me to name a case_id in the new_case_round_path, so it gives me this error before it loads the pick_case view:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"rounds"} missing required keys: [:case_id]
```

How can I reference the route that the form needs to submit to when the required information for the route is being entered in the form?

Comment: In a normal way with the nested routes, you can't achieve it what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

> No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"rounds"} missing
>   required keys: [:case_id]

The error clearly says that `case_id` is missing. Rails expects `case_id` to be present which can't be provided in your situation as you are creating a ***new case instance***.

One way to resolve your situation is to use [***Shallow Nesting***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) which provides the ***route*** for ***new case***

```
resources :cases do
  resources :rounds, shallow :true
end
```

Now, when you run `rake routes`, you will find a route for new case as below

```
new_case GET   /cases/new(.:format)  cases#new
```

So that in your `pick_case` view, you can change the `form` to

```
<%= form_tag new_case_path, method: :get do |f| %>

  <%= f.select_tag :case_id,
    options_for_select(Case.all.collect { |c| [c.title, c.id] }),
    class: "chosen-select" %><br/>

  <%= f.submit_tag "Create round", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Which creates a ***case instance*** first before redirecting to the ***round form***

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think there was a small misunderstanding, though. I do the case already exists, but I want to have a page where you pick the case and in order to redirect to the new_case_round_path, the user would have already picked a case for me to reference the path I want the form to get.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a work-around for the answer, I feel like there's probably a more elegant way. I added `post 'get_case' => rounds#get_case` to `routes.rb`

I added this to my rounds controller:

```
def get_case
  id = params[:case_id]
  if id
    redirect_to new_case_round_path(case_id: id)
  else
    flash[:danger] = "An error occured. Please try again"
    redirect_to pick_case_path
  end
end
```

And this is my new pick_case view:

```
<%= form_tag get_case_path do %>

  <%= select_tag :case_id,
    options_for_select(map_with_id(Case, :title)),
    class: "chosen-select" %><br/>

  <%= submit_tag "Create round", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```